# Discord Bot intent Python issue

Tags: python

```
so this is my code
```

import discord
import  os

this is the part that's confusing to me

```
 client = discord.Client(intents = idk)


 @client.event
 async def on_ready():
 print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client.user:
  return

if message.content.startswith('?daily facts'):
  await message.channel.send('Hello, im here with your daily facts. Do you know that the bee movie took 4 years to complete!! And it also took a million man hours!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

```
the thing that doesnt make sense is the intents 
so im trying to learn how to code and trying to do a discord bot and it says intents not found so im wondering how i could fix that.
```

Im trying to find out how to Fix the intents
here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    client = discord.Client()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

```

Comment: only the client = discord.Client(Intents = idk)

Comment: Please add additional information and edits to your question and not the comments. You can [edit] your question. And please take a look at [help] for formatting tips.